# Setting ORDER BY to non-alphabetical

Tags: php, sql-order-by

So I am currently trying to ORDER BY a field, and it orders by the alphabet.  Instead, I want it to order by the variables that I set it to, if this is possible.  Here is the query I am sending to the db:

```
$player_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `user_id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY position");
```

The answers are GK, DF, MF, ST and I want it to be sorted in that order, the only issue is, because it does it alphabetically, GK & DF get swapped around.  Any help would be very useful!

Comment: please give more detail about *"I want it to order by the variables that I set it to"*

Comment: `ORDER BY FIELD(position, 'GK', 'DF', 'MF', 'ST')`

Comment: I did, underneath, I said the table column that I wish for it to be sorted by.  The results of this are printed into a table, all works, just the sorting that needs touching up to sort by position: GK first, DF, MF, ST, instead of the alphabetical default GK, DF, MF, ST

Answer (score 2):

You can order them by doing something like this:

```
$player_list = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `user_id`='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY FIELD(position, 'GK', 'DF', 'MF', 'ST')");
```